# Bolt CMS having same path for two different routes

Tags: routes, bolt-cms

See the following contentTypes:

```
pages:
    name: Pages
    singular_name: Page
    fields:
    # etc

blogitems:
    name: Blogitems
    singular_name: Blog
    fields:
    # etc
```

I do not want blogs to appear as `/blog/slug`, but as `slug` just like pages.

How is it possible to have this correctly defined in routes? With my last try I came up this this which returns an error on normal pages:

```
pagebinding:
     path: /{slug}
     defaults:
         _controller: controller.frontend:record
         contenttypeslug: page
     contenttype: pages

blogitemsbinding:
    path:  /{slug}
    defaults:
        _controller: controller.frontend:record
    requirements:
        contenttype: blogitems
```

The problem is, when I leave them both, the first one of the above will work, but the lower one will not.

Who can shed a light on this one, because it is unfortunately not documented here: https://docs.bolt.cm/3.4/configuration/routing#

Answer (score 3):

Routing in Silex/Symfony is regex based and matches are binary so unfortunately once a route matches then that is the only one that will be run, hence why the first route matches and the second is ignored.

There isn't a way to do what you want out of the box — to achieve it you would need to point the first match to your own controller method instead of the default `controller.frontend:record` in your own method you could loop through the contenttypes you wanted to support and keep looking till you found a slug that matched irrespective of the contenttype.

Bolt has not been able to support this as a standard feature since it causes quite a lot of complications in edge cases, eg how to behave if a slug is available in more than one contenttype or whether the backend should allow some contenttypes to generate identical slugs.